# Why does MLLib GenerateLinearInput internally multiply variance by 12.0?

Tags: scala, random, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Consider the `generateLinearInput` method from MLLib `LinearDataGenerator`:

Here is the signature of the method:

```
  def generateLinearInput(
      intercept: Double,
      weights: Array[Double],
      xMean: Array[Double],
      xVariance: Array[Double],
      nPoints: Int,
      seed: Int,
      eps: Double): Seq[LabeledPoint] = {
```

and here is the core logic for generating the raw data points:

```
val rnd = new Random(seed)
val x = Array.fill[Array[Double]](nPoints)(
  Array.fill[Double](weights.length)(rnd.nextDouble()))

x.foreach { v =>
  var i = 0
  val len = v.length
  while (i < len) {
    v(i) = (v(i) - 0.5) * math.sqrt(12.0 * xVariance(i)) + xMean(i)
    i += 1
  }
```

Notice in particular **the `12.0` scaling factor** on the variance.  ***What is the purpose of that factor?***

For completeness: here is the remainder of that method - in which the input linear function is applied to the x/domain values to generate the output y/range values:

```
val y = x.map { xi =>
  blas.ddot(weights.length, xi, 1, weights, 1) + intercept + eps * rnd.nextGaussian()
}
y.zip(x).map(p => LabeledPoint(p._1, Vectors.dense(p._2)))
```

Comment: This probably belongs on [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com) but to give you a clue a variance of _unif(a, b)_ is equal to _(b - a) ^ 2 / 12_

Comment: fair enough - but why not make that an answer - and we can close this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have random variable *X*

[image]

then [its variance is equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/728059)

[image]

So this piece of code

```
v(i) = (v(i) - 0.5) * math.sqrt(12.0 * xVariance(i)) + xMean(i)
```

should be equivalent to:

[image]

where *a'* and *b'* are the parameters of the desired uniform distribution and *EX'* is mean of the desired distribution. If you set `xMean` to 0 the rest of the code centers input data around 0 and adjusts spread.

Comment: do you have a link showing *why* the variance were equal to (a-b)^2/12

Comment: thanks for that (that's the fewest characters allowed in a comment ;) )